# Huge performance problems with foreach

Tags: php, performance, foreach

I am looking for performance leaks in my script, maybe anyone knows some genious stuff?

Actually I have huge array (3mil. datasets) and it looks like this (simplified):

```
[2]=>
  array(11) {
    ["A"]=>
    string(10) "10-12-1995"
    ["B"]=>
    NULL
    ["C"]=>
    NULL

[3]=>
  array(11) {
    ["A"]=>
    string(10) "31-12-1955"
    ["B"]=>
    NULL
    ["C"]=>
    string(6) "random"
```

My functions has to check, if the $StartDate is in $sheetData[$i]['A'].
I haven't found any better idea and it costs > 10 seconds to check the
whole array :(

```
function searchForDate($StartDate, $sheetData)
        {
            foreach($sheetData as $key => &$val)
            {
                if ($val['A'] === $StartDate)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: You are doing a linear search through 3 million data points.  Can you arrange for the data to be ordered by (or indexed by) date?  If so, you can perform a binary search instead.  I see no obvious reason why this should take 10 seconds for any modern language, on any modern hardware, assuming the data is entirely in memory.  What language is this?

Comment: What language or system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is PHP, because that's what it looks like, you can try a built-in function to see if it offers better performance:

`array_search($StartDate, array_column($sheetData, 'A'));`

if not, then your best bet is to do what @EricJ suggested and see if the data can be sorted/indexed in some fashion to perform a binary search.